# What will be the correct indentation of this python3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, indentation

I'm getting the error

```
for quote in quotes:
                   ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any o
uter indentation level

code below :-

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Query the price once every N seconds.
    for _ in iter(range(N)):
        quotes = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())

        """ ----------- Update to get the ratio --------------- """
        prices = {}
    for quote in quotes:
      stock, bid_price, ask_price, price = getDataPoint(quote)
      print ("Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock,bid_price, ask_price, price))
    print ("Ratio %s" % getRatio(prices['ABC'], prices['DEF']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check brackets again in here whether they placed correctly.

```
quotes = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())
```

Comment: checked brackets are okay there!